# How do I change the maintenance database for Postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin

I'm running PostgreSQL version 9.0 on OSX version 10.6.6.  Somehow one of my development databases has become the maintenance db, not postgres (this db also exists).  I can't find any documentation on how to change/set the maintenance db back to postgres.

I can't drop my development database because of this issue...

Comment: I believe the maintenance db is the one with the same name as your os user, at least that's how it works in windows and linux, try logging with a different user and then connect to postgres.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "maintenance DB" in Postgres

Comment: When I log into pgAdmin and attempt to drop a database, I get the error message: "Dropping database not allowed.  Maintenance database can't be dropped."  The db in question is not postgres but another db I created for testing.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this may be technically true but not in practice. Or at least if you use pgadmin it is not true in practice. The db designated by pgadmin as being the "maintenance db" is very important to the functioning of pgadmin. It has been used by pgadmin forever.

Comment: @BillR: so it's a pgAdmin specific database. I hardly ever use pgAdmin so I never noticed that special requirement it apparently has.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name I read something recently on the postgres hackers mail list that leads me to believe that postgres core will have some sort of concept at least of a maintenance db. It might be something like in other RDBMS (SQL Server for one) that has a core db that is used as the template db. I know Postgres has the template schemas, but this might be something more in depth. Not sure. If it is there already then I haven't seen it, but I believe this was in the context of a 9.2 or later release. Time will tell if this is true.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not entirely clear on this, but do you mean the "Maintenance DB" selection in pgAdmin III?

Select the server in your "object browser" pane; right click -> Properties

The fifth field is "Maintenance DB"

Comment: Yes, I've been trying to drop the db via pgAdmin (per my comment above).  Unfortunately the "Maintenance DB" property is read-only.

Comment: Solved this.  I was able to drop the database using rake (rake db:drop).  When I opened pgAdmin I was then notified that the maintenance database did not exist.  I could then update the "Maintenance DB" selection as described by intgr (it was previously read-only)

Comment: @gsiener: the "Maintenance DB" property is *never* read only. besides chosing from the proposed values you can always type in any database name.

Answer (score 25):

You can change maintenance db from `pgAdmin` but you have to be disconnected from the database engine to be able to do that.

First disconnect:

[image]

Then in the database server properties:

[image]

Choose the desired maintenance database:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Maintenance db  field is read-only , you can't change it.So you should keep your server properties somewhere and create new server with these properties and set maintenance db **"postgres"**. Now you are able to drop database.

Comment: This answer is false. The field is not read-only, you just need to disconnect from the server, see the above answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15856040/7769052

Answer (score 3):

The command line option is :

```
psql -U intelison -c "UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate=false, datallowconn=true WHERE datname = '<your_database_name>'"
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for the command line option. Could I please ask you to explain what the components of this command mean/do?