# pgAdmin can't see pgAgent Job scheduler

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I've been trying to install PgAgent on PostgreSQL.

As you can see, I have it in my catalog and in the extensions.

But why it doesn't appear on my tablespaces?

[image]

I also cant reset the PG admin section

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

pgAgent Jobs do not appear in the *Tablespaces* unless you manually create one with this name :)

The Jobs are listed in a separated section on pgAdmin

[image]

Keep in mind that in the pgAdmin connection you have to set the *maintenance database* to the database you have installed pgAgent. In my case, the `postgres` database:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Jim Jones. Thanks for the help. I don't get it. So will right click on ''dev'' and ''Create - Tablespace'' that I called pgAgent Jobs and what i should put in the ''location tab''?

Comment: To my knowledge tablespaces have nothing to do with pgAgent jobs. pgAgent jobs appear in a separated section, which appears if you follow the instructions I mentioned above.

Comment: please see my update seems i cant reset in the maintenance database...?

Comment: Create a new connection and set the database sanisphere as the maintenance database and see if the jobs appear. I'm not sure if pgAdmin allows editing the connection like this - can't test it right now.

Comment: It did! Thanks a lot, you have no ideas how long i search!

Comment: Believe me, it took me ages to find it out as well:) good luck with pgAgent:)

Comment: Worked for me, I disconected the server, typed the name of the pgAgent database in the Maintenance DB, and connected again. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695954/how-do-i-change-the-maintenance-database-for-postgres

Comment: what do you mean by 'unless you create one with this name'? A Tablespace called pgAgent Jobs?  Demonstrative pronouns aren't very demonstrative.

Comment: @OptoNPO I honestly do not remember what I meant there (it's been many years). Perhaps a joke? ;) I hope one can see that the pgAgent related objects are stored somewhere else. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

pgAgent needs to be created in postgres database in order to show up.

Comment: Wow... postgres database !!!

Answer (score 0):

Steps:
1. Install the pgagent to a particular database in a server.
2. create a new connection in pgadmin where give maintainance database as the once to which the pgagent is installed.

This will eneable the pg agent jobs option in the connection database to become visible

Answer (score 0):

pgAgent needs to be created in postgres database in order to show up.

I got a pgagent job when I processed create extension in postgres databases.
Thank you.

Comment: The pgAgent Jobs folder is created, but there is nothing in the subfolder.
Is this correct?